Is it possible to make an ODE-based system component that can be used repeatedly?
The background to my probelm:
The problem I want to address is the seismic response of a bridge after installing dampers. The kc component here refers to the dampers. My main system is the bridge, where x1 and x2 represent the displacements of the bridge, and x0 is the base displacement during an earthquake. Multiple dampers need to be installed on the bridge, and the governing equations for each damper are the same, with the main difference being the input for each damper. I would prefer not to write the equations for each damper repeatedly.
So, what I'm doing is somewhat similar to component in Simulink or System Modeler. The kc component is the basic element that I need to express using differential equations, and then I want to use multiple kc components in the bridge model.
The bridge and dampers are coupled; the dampers, i.e., the kc components, receive the bridge's displacement and output the damping force, while the structure receives the damping force from the kc dampers and outputs displacement.
The naive code I tried:
The component model kc below is an extremely simplified version to illustrate my problem. My actual component model is much more complex.
kc is a component defined by differential equations with parameters k and c.
The input is a time-dependent function xinfun, and the output is also a time-dependent function F.
The most straightforward idea might be to define this model as a function based on NDSolve, where both the input and output are time-dependent functions. However, I don't know how to define this function.
So, I tried using the ParametricNDSolve method, treating the input function as a parameter for NDSolve.
My questions:

I would like to know if it is possible to repeatedly call the model kc by defining kc as a NDSolve based function?

My ParametricNDSolve way feels clumsy; NDSolve always complains that the parameter is not a numerical value. How can I improve this method?


ClearAll["Global`*"] // Quiet;
tend = 50;

(* define a kc component *)
kcPar[k_, c_] := 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{F'[t]/k + F[t]/c == xinfun, 
    F[0] == 0}, {F[t]}, {t, 0, tend}, {xinfun}];
kc[k_, c_, xinfun_(*?NumericQ*)] := kcPar[k, c][xinfun][[1]]
Plot[kc[1, 20, Sin[10 t]], {t, 0, tend}]

(* use kc as multiple components in a system model *)
m1 = 10;
m2 = 200;
x0[t_] := Sin[t]/10;


xsol = NDSolve[{
    m1 (x1''[t] + x0''[t]) == -kc[5, 10, x1[t]] -
      kc[2, 2, x2[t] - x1[t]],
    m2 (x2''[t] + x0''[t]) == -kc[5, 1, x2[t] - x1[t]],
    x1[0] == x2[0] == x1'[0] == x2'[0] == 0}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 
    tend}];

Plot[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. xsol // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}]


It is not entirely clear which equations you are trying to solve. Can you give any explanations about your model?

@AlexTrounev Thank you very much for your attention. I have added the background to my question and hope I have clarified everything. If there is anything that is not clear, please let me know. Have a nice day! Thanks :)

Thank you very much for the model explanation. It looks like you try to solve system of integrodifferential equations using NDSolve. Note, that sometimes it possibly but not in this case,

As Alex Trounev noted in a comment, the computation given in the question asks NDSolve to solve a system of integrodifferential equations, which it cannot do in this instance.  However, the problem can be solved by integrating the underlying five ODEs in parallel.  To do so, replace the three instances of kc with f1[t], f2[t], and f3[t]`, respectively.  The equations for the f's can be written simply by,
eqp[F_, k_, c_, xinfun_] := F'[t]/k + F[t]/c == xinfun

where the three f's vanish at t = 0.  With this substitution the calculation becomes,
eqs = {m1  (x1''[t] + x0''[t]) == -f1[t] - f2[t], 
       m2  (x2''[t] + x0''[t]) == -f3[t], 
       eqp[f1, 5, 10, x1[t]], 
       eqp[f2, 2, 2, x2[t] - x1[t]], 
       eqp[f3, 5, 1, x2[t] - x1[t]], 
       x1[0] == x2[0] == x1'[0] == x2'[0] == f1[0] == f2[0] == f3[0] == 0};
xsol = NDSolveValue[eqs, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, tend}];

Plot[xsol[[1]], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
Plot[xsol[[2]], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x1},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]



Incidentally, the ODEs for the f's can be eliminated in a straightforward fashion, if desired.
